# Use Web Service CRM to Get Data in InfoPath 2013

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, dynamics-crm, infopath

When I use Web Service CRM to Get Data in InfoPath 2013, I get the following Error:

> ***Error message*** : WSDL Service : Port definitions not found while processing the Service Organization Service ..  incorrect Parameter. WSDLReader  Failed to analyse WSDL file.. Incorrect Parameter

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l91Z.png)

Comment: can you translate the error message to English

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this will not work.
The CRM web services are too complex for InfoPath to be able to work with. You must remember that InfoPath is designed to work with fairly simple and straightforward web services. The CRM ones are anything but that.

If you really want to consume CRM data in InfoPath forms, you may need to create a custom wrapper web service with predefined methods that InfoPath can understand.